# select and insert checkboxes to mysql using php

Tags: jquery, ajax

**This is my form to add the services the customer availed**:

[image: this is my form to add the services the customer availed]

**This image is my table from database**:

[image: this image is my table from database]

**Here is from my PHP code to display services with the checkboxes**:

[image: here is from my PHP code to display services with the checkboxes]

**The question is:** How can I insert the selected checkboxes to my database table. This image shows my table where I can save the selected database

[image]

If I use jQuery how could I apply it and insert to my table?

> This code is from my create_serviceAvailed.php

```
<?php include('assets/session.php'); ?>
<?php include('php/insert_serviceAvailed.php'); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Add Availed Service</title>
    <?php include('assets/style.php') ?>
  </head>
<body>
    <?php include('assets/topbar_index.php'); ?>
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Add Service Availed</h2>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="small-6 cell">
            <label> Reciept No.
              <input type="number" name="reciept_no" placeholder="Reciept No" required>
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="small-12 cell">
              <label> Customer ID
                <select name="customer_id">
                 <?php 
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Customer";
                    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                  ?>
                  <option value="<?php echo $row['customer_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['first_name'];?></option>
                  <?php
                      }
                    }
                  ?>
                </select>
              </label>
            </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <?php $result1 = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM Services");
            while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {?>
            <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" name="<?php echo $data[$count] ?>"  value="<?php echo $ServiceID; ?>" ><?php echo $row1['Serv_Name']; ?>
            <?php
            }?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="button expanded" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="Foundation/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="Foundation/js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="Foundation/js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="Foundation/js/app.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

This code is from insert_serviceAvailed.php

```
<?php
$user_id = $_SESSION['username'];

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'beautysalon');

//check connection
if($db === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// adding contact
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $reciept_no = $_POST['reciept_no'];
  $customer_id = $_POST['customer_id'];
  $Services_checked = $_POST['Services_checked'];


  $sql = "INSERT INTO `Services_availed` (`reciept_no`, `customer_id`, `Services_checked`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$reciept_no', '$customer_id', '$Services_checked', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    if($result == true){
      header('Location:service_availed.php');
    }else{
      echo "Something went wrong";
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the name of checkbox as `name="<?php echo $data[$count] ?>"` now store this variable data in mysql

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and it didn't work or I don't understand it further

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify your question a little more. What do you want to exactly do with jquery here?

Edit:
And next time please post your real code and not a screenshot of any kind, thank you.

Answer:
In your "Add Service Availed" page you have to give the form an action to send all the inputs to. Here it would be something like this:

```
<form action ="insert_serviceAvailed.php" method="post">
PUT HERE ALL INPUTS
</form>
```

On the insert_serviceAvailed.php you can simply access all variables like this:
$_POST['Services_checked'] = do something.

Your question has nothing to do with jquery.

Kind regards.

Comment: thanks for the answer I try to Edit my Post and post the real code

Comment: Another question: Is it possible to have both checkboxes checked? If not, you should use some form of radio buttons so you cannot press "save" when 2 ticks are made.

Comment: It was dependent on the service you added in the database if how many services you put in there, Sorry for my Grammar :)

Comment: I want exactly with the jquery to get the selected checkboxes and insert it to the table as strings